# Preventing Jenkins building (thus re-deploying) released versions of Maven projects

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'd like to prevent Jenkins building (thus re-deploying) released versions of Maven projects. Artifactory (rightly) doesn't allow released versions to be redeployed.

I'm using a Maven profile "jenkins" for all builds run in Jenkins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<profile>
    <id>jenkins</id>
    <!-- This profile is activated by the "-P jenkins" switch when run on 
        the build server by Jenkins (continuous integration) -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Jenkins should only build -SNAPSHOTs -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <evaluateBeanshell>
                                <condition>"${project.version}".endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")</condition>
                                <message>Jenkins should only build -SNAPSHOT versions</message>
                                </evaluateBeanshell>
                            </rules>
                            <fail>true</fail>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: A lot of people are complaining online about deployment failures with the Maven Release Plugin (dreaded 400 error, etc). I'd bet many times their Jenkins instance is configured to deploy before they can hit perform in the console. Two deployments equals failure. This solves the problem definitively. Thanks!!!